# On $t\mapsto\max_{0\le s\le t}|f(s)|$ with $f$ $\alpha$-Holder function s.t. $f(0)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf, holder-spaces

Let $f:[0,T]\to\Bbb R$ be an $\alpha$-Holder continuous function with $1/2<\alpha\le1$, such that $f(0)=0$.

I was asking myself a couple of things:

1) what can we say about the regularity of
$$
t\mapsto\max_{0\le s\le t}|f(s)|=:h(t)\;?
$$
I proved that it is $\alpha$-Holder too, but I don't know if it is *exactly* $\alpha$-Holder, or if there exists $\alpha<\alpha'\le1$ such that it is $\alpha'$-Holder too.

2)fixed $s=0$, in MO someone said me that (observe that $h(0)=0$)
$$
\lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{|h(t)|}{t^{\alpha}}
$$
doesn't exist in general.
It is easy to prove that the $\limsup_{t\to 0^+}$ is finite but what I'm really interested in, is to show that
$$
\liminf_{t\to 0^+}\frac{|h(t)|}{t^{\alpha}}>0.
$$

Ant hint is welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Consider two scenarios:

1. $f$ is positive and increasing. Then $h=f$, so there is no improvement in Hölder exponent.
2. $f$ is positive and decreasing. Then $h\equiv f(0)$, which shows 
   $$\liminf_{t\to s^+}\frac{|h(t)-h(s)|}{(t-s)^{\alpha}}$$

may well be zero.

So, the continuity may stay the same or improve a lot.

Comment: many thanks for the answer. I have edited my question; I wrote it in a more general way at first, but it is the case to write my specific problem, as I just did.

Comment: @Joe, You have proved that $h$ is $\alpha$-Hölder and monotone increasing. For a more concrete example, consider $f(x) = x^{\alpha}$ on $[0, \infty)$.

Comment: I'm melting. Sorry. But I mean: $x^{\alpha}$ is not Holder only near $0$; except this it's very regular. I refer to nowhere differentiable functions.